# Incompatible types. 'this' could be instantiated with arbitrary type which could be unrelated . .

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am using Sequelize with some third-party library-generated interfaces for my various tables to make Sequelize work really well with my TypeScript application.

Sequelize provides an interface, `Instance<A>`, that represents the result of a lookup for a `SELECT ... LIMIT 1` query. It has all the columns of that row plus various helpers like toJSON(), which returns a JSON representation of just the columns with none of the helpers.

My 3PL-generated interfaces represent the instances for all my tables plus attributes for all my tables, plus a bunch of nice stuff I've omitted.

In my code, I want to run the Sequelize query (which returns a `Promise<Instance<A>>`) and then invoke the `toJSON()` function so that my data service returns JSON representations of the data without the extra functions like `toJSON` (so I can serialize the data and send it over HTTP). In effect, return the `attributes` (just the columnar data) rather than the `instance` (columnar data plus various non-serializable stuff like methods and circular data).

I want to create a function `extractData: (Instance<A>) => A` that takes an instance and returns the attributes so I can do `query().then(extractData)` instead of `query().then(result => result.toJSON())`. This is to improve readability.

However, I am running into an error with my `extractData` function: `Argument of type '<A>(data:Instance<A>)=>A' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a:tableInstance)=>tableAttribute'. Types of parameter 'data' and 'a' are incompatible. Types of property 'Model' are incompatible. /*snip*/ 'this' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'tableInstance'`.

I do not understand what incompatible types they're talking about. Furthermore, if I write a helper interface that is a simplified form of `Instance` called `$Instance` that only has the `toJSON` method, and then use that in my `extractData` function, the error goes away. Why?

There are many other questions similar to this one on SO, but they all have slightly different variations, like people confusing a generic with a class name (which I haven't done here). I can't find one that is on point (indeed, I looked for twenty minutes through many questions before taking thirty minutes to compose my own question; finding an already-answered one would have been much faster than writing this).

(I can also make the error go away by trying `query().then(extractData.bind(extractData))` but then TypeScript detects the return value as `unknown` instead of `tableAttribute`.)

See below for simplified code of what I've discussed:

```js
// simplified for this SO post from Sequelize types 3.30.4
interface Model<I, A> /*extends some interfaces*/ {
  /* some props, methods */
}
interface Instance<A> {
  Model: Model<this, A>
  toJSON(): A
}

// 3PL-generated sequelize typescript interfaces/types
interface tableAttribute { /* models SQL table */
  id: number
  foo: string
  bar: string
}

interface tableInstance extends Instance<tableAttribute>, tableAttribute { }

// My code
interface $Instance<A> {
  toJSON(): A
}

const extractData = <A>(data: Instance<A>) => data.toJSON() // Instance<A> => A
const $extractData = <A>(data: $Instance<A>) => data.toJSON() // $Instance<A> => A

declare const getData: () => Promise<tableInstance>

const fetch = () => getData().then(extractData) // ERROR!
const $fetch = () => getData().then($extractData) // () => Promise<tableAttribute>
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error. Could you please add reproducible code with typescript playground link?

Comment: I'm also not seeing any error by copy and pasting your code into the typescript playground, so I think you got rid of it by removing all of the contents of `Model`.  I suspect the error has to do with inheritance/extends and the value of `this` passed to `Model`.  But honestly you've already solved the problem.  Just rename `$Instance<A>` to `Extractable<A>` such that you can call `extractData` on any object with a `toJSON` method.  You don't need to explicitly implement it in your classes/interfaces because you're already implementing it.